# How can I add two different features as a foreign key to my SQL Column?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, foreign-keys

[image: My Car Table and I want to add 2 foreign key as you see]

I have a Car table in my Sql Data and every car has own BrandId that declared every Brands in "Brands" table as a foreign key. I'm just wondering what if I want to add two different BrandId together in my one Car>BrandId Column, what would I do? How can it be possible for adding two features as a foreign key in one spesific column?

Here is my Car Tables Code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars] (
[CarId]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CarName]    VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[ColorId]    INT           NULL,
[BrandId]    INT           NULL,
[ModelYear]  VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[DailyPrice] DECIMAL (18)  NULL,
[Details]    VARCHAR (255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CarId] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([ColorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Colors] ([ColorId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([BrandId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([BrandId])
);
```

And here te code of my Brands table;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Brands] (
[BrandId]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[BrandName] VARCHAR (255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BrandId] ASC)
);
```

Comment: If you need to link two items (e.g. brand and car) in a many to many relationship, the typical approach would be to use a [Junction Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Comment: What, exactly, does *brand* mean, and what car has two brands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create your table as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars] (
[CarId]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CarName]    VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[ColorId]    INT           NULL,
[BrandId1]    INT           NULL,
[BrandId2]    INT           NULL,
[ModelYear]  VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[DailyPrice] DECIMAL (18)  NULL,
[Details]    VARCHAR (255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CarId] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([ColorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Colors] ([ColorId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([BrandId1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([BrandId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([BrandId2] REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([BrandId])
```

Comment: What if Sometimes I want to add single foreign, is this code gonna meets my demands? @Tashil Tashil

Comment: For you query just do the following : 
I forgot to add [BrandId2] as a column up but it should look like this
[BrandId2] INT NULL